# Is the honors program worth it?

Tags: chemistry

Chemistry major here, let preface this by saying I don't know anything about anything. That being said, as a student attending a school that is not very well known for its academics, I always figured that I needed to do whatever I could to be competitive. My fear is that I'll get into the world of academia and find out that I'm leagues behind my peers in terms of education. I'm probably overthinking things, but I just don't have enough information to know where I stand. So the honor's program sounded like the obvious decision at the time. In addition to the sweet-sounding benefits listed on the program page, it would maybe help close the gap between the difficulty of my school's chemistry program vs a top 50 program.

I did some looking around, and it seems that at most schools, an honor's program is something that students are jumping to get into. It's considered a pretty big deal to be part of it. But from asking around my school, the sentiment seems to be the exact opposite. Most students here don't tend to respect the honors program from what I can tell. They say that the extra work isn't worth it, so most tend to drop out after sophomore year. And I think that's because the benefits aren't as meaningful to, say, a CS major. I think to one entering the workforce immediately after graduation, honors college holds much less weight. My guess is that because my peers are here to put in their 4 years and join the workforce, they don't really care about things like prestige or standing out. Which makes sense for them, but coming from someone who has different goals, I don't know if their opinions are applicable to me. I have yet to talk to a hard science major about this, so I don't know how much importance something like honors college carries to us.

To be perfectly honest, a lot of what honors college entails just sounds like fun to me. I would love the opportunity to do it. But I can't say it's worth it if the extra workload has the possibility of tanking my GPA. Does anybody have any experience with an honors program at school, and how it's affected their career and their enjoyment of college? Thanks in advanced.